# Adding new System Call in Minix

Tags: c, operating-system, system, system-calls, minix

I am trying to create a new system call in Minix 3.3.  At first i just want to create simple printmsg() call that will write "Hello World" on screen.
I looked various tutorials on internet and still couldn't find out solution.

- I defined my sys call number in **callnr.h** like this `#define PM_PRINTMSG (PM BASE + 48)` and i increased number of sys calls `#define NR_PM_CALLS 49`.
- In **table.c** I added `CALL(PM_PRINTMSG) = doprintmsg`.
- In **proto.h** I described function prototype `int do_printmsg(void);
- Function implementation is written in **misc.c**. I added `#include <stdio.h>` and made Hello World function `int do printmsg(){ printf("I am a system call"); return 0; }`

When I test my system call in user program `_syscall(PM_PROC_NR, PM_PRINTMSG, &m);` I don't get any errors but no printf is displayed.

So, is it possible to printf messages from system calls since i had to add `<stdio.h>` myself in **misc.c** or i missed some steps. I forgot to mention that i go in /usr/src/releasetools and type `make services` and `make install` respectively to recompile kernel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out what was the problem, so i will post answer if someone needs this in future. I did everything well in this example but i failed to compile kernel.
 The location was correct which is usr/src/releasetools, but command needed is `make hdboot`. Also i figured out my PC somehow wasnt working well with this virtual machines and i had many errors while compiling even though i didn't change anything. When i switched to laptop everything worked fine.
My conclusion is sometimes there is just something wrong on your machine so you should try and test problems on different ones

Comment: For a long time I was doing `make; make install` in pm server directory. This really helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, with the continuous evolution of MINIX 3 and its series, it will be wise to only follow the developer's guide directly from the minix3.org website [**here**](https://wiki.minix3.org/doku.php?id=developersguide:newkernelcall)

Although you managed to solve the problem yourself, the latest version of MINIX3 (MINIX 3.4) will follow a more advanced and suitable approach.

Please visit the [**link**](https://wiki.minix3.org/doku.php?id=developersguide:newkernelcall) to learn more.

Many regards.

Ola